# amcharts 4 get series id dynamically

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

multipal series amcharts 
assign the id for series but at event fire trying catch the series id but its shows undefined

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/toggling-multiple-series-with-a-single-legend-item/

```
*var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
series.id='101'
series.dataItem.setProperty("Id",101);
series.columns.template.propertyFields.fill = "color";
series.columns.template.propertyFields.stroke = "color";

series.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  alert("Clicked on " + ev.target.dataItem.categoryX + ": " + ev.target.dataItem.valueY+":"+ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
});*
```

Clicked on Distribution: 1500:undefined

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here. What does the link which has Line Series have to do with Columns? Usually an object has a `component` property which is a reference to the series it belongs to. I would try `ev.target.component` or `ev.target.dataItem.component` to see if it's a reference to the columns' series. If it is, then you should be able to just find `.id` from it.

Answer (score -1):

try this 
columnSeries.columns.template.events.on("hit", function(ev) {
  alert("Clicked on " + ev.target.dataItem.categoryX + ": " + ev.target.dataItem.valueY+":"+series.id);
});

Comment: It would be better if you format your code properly and explain what exactly it is doing